# How to access the download mode of a device with a outdated bootloader?

Tags: samsung, bootloader, unbricking, downloading

I accidentally flashed some outdated bootloader firmware and now I cannot seem to access the bootloader I tried holding the vol up + power and both to volume buttons + power but it  made the phone vibrate and reboot.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3573865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SM-A405FN with Exynos chipset? I am not aware of any emergency download mode. Let battery drain for few days. Press and keep holding both Volume buttons when plug in charger.

If you still can't reach download mode, buy JIG dongle (your last hope)