# Unbrick Samsung A40 not going into download mode

Tags: samsung, unbricking

I accidentally installed an outdated bootloader to my device and I cannot seem to access the download mode I also tried to access the recovery and I tried letting the device run out of battery by holding down the power button for a long time. And then connecting the phone to the computer while holding both the volume and power buttons. It only shows the circle with a lightning bolt in it. It also shows a cyan box with red text reading " rev. check fail. Device: 4 binary: 2 (otb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the download mode of a device with a outdated bootloader?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241521/how-to-access-the-download-mode-of-a-device-with-a-outdated-bootloader)

Comment: @alecxs No it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Since download mode isn't accessible, taking it to the service center is the only way to unbrick it.